# Is there a way to transpose rows with an varying number of columns and replicate cells based on number of columns?

Tags: google-apps-script, pivot-table

I have a Google Form featuring an name, date, and checkbox field capable of generating multiple choices, anywhere from 1 to 50. I'm looking to have this form filled monthly by hundreds of users.
When the data is exported to Google Sheets and multiple checkboxes are ticked, the output goes into a single field with a comma separator.

[image]

I've split that data using an array formula:

```
(=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(GI:GI)=1,"",IF(ISBLANK(C:C),,SPLIT(C:C,","))))
```

So that every checkbox becomes is given its own cell.

[image]

I would like to transpose and replicate the name based on the number of columns following the name:

[image]

I've tried a number of transpose, array and split formulas with no luck, and the pivot table. Since there would be several users and multiple column entries, I'm thinking that a script is needed.

Any helps would be appreciated.